# Monthly Data Query With Group by

Tags: sql-server

I have table  order with fields id, department, date and amount.
I want query which returns last 3 months or 6 months records of department total transactions and total amount. if there is no transactions for any month i want 0 as total transactions and amount.

I tried several queries but i fail to generate output as i want two group by.

Here is Something what i have tried.

```
Select SUM(ISNULL(od.Amount,0)) as Points, Count(ISNULL(od.OrderId,0)) as Transactions,
DATEPART(MONTH, od.OrderDate) as Month, max(DeptId)
from POR_OrderDetails od
where 
cast(od.OrderDate as date) BETWEEN cast(dateadd(month, -3, GETDATE()) as date) and cast(getdate() as date) 
group by DATEPART(YEAR, od.OrderDate),DATEPART(MONTH, od.OrderDate), od.DeptId
```

**Test Data**

```
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
| OrderId | Amount | DeptId | OrderDate |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 1       | 10     | 1      | 15/3/2020 |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 2       | 10     | 3      | 1/3/2020  |
|         |        |        |           |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 3       | 10     | 2      | 25/2/2020 |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4       | 20     | 1      | 1/2/2020  |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| Month | TotalAmount | TotalTransactions | DeptId |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 1     | 0           | 0                 | 1      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 1     | 0           | 0                 | 2      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 1     | 0           | 0                 | 3      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 2     | 20          | 1                 | 1      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 2     | 10          | 1                 | 2      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 2     | 0           | 0                 | 3      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 3     | 10          | 1                 | 1      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 3     | 0           | 0                 | 2      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
| 3     | 10          | 1                 | 3      |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest creating a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table), as it will help here, and they are an invaluable additional to any instance.

Once you have that set up, it's as simple as cross joining your department table (which I assume you have) to your Calendar Table, and then making a `LEFT JOIN` to your Department Orders table. So something like this:

```
SELECT C.MonthNo,
       SUM(DOAmount) AS TotalAmount,
       COUNT(DOOrderID) AS TotalTransactions,
       D.DeptID
FROM dbo.Department D
     CROSS JOIN dbo.Calendar C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.DepartmentOrder DO ON D.DeptID = DO.DeptID
                                     AND C.CalendarDate = DO.OrderDate
WHERE C.CalendarDate >= '20200101'
  AND C.CalendarDate < '20200401'
GROUP BY C.MonthNo,
         D.DeptID
ORDER BY C.MonthNo,
         D.DeptID;
```

Comment: i am new to concept 'Calender Table', so i couldnt figure out dbo.Calendar would actual table and what it can be included?

Comment: Have a look at the link I provided, @Ravi . There are also 100's of resources on how to create a calendar tale other than that article. Once you have a calendar table, as I show, this is quite trivial.